# How to logout user if the session array is already expired

Tags: php, codeigniter, keycloak, idl, idp

I have a system with IDP keycloak login integrated. The idle time for session expiry is set to 20 minutes. After that 20 minutes of idle time, the user's session data expires automatically.But now I want a data from session to delete the user session from the keycloak server. I don't find any way to do it. Can anyone suggest me a good solution to logout the user from keycloak after idle timeout.

```html
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$idp_data = $this->session->userdata('idp_token');
                     
$ad_data['session_id']=$idp_data['session_state'];  
$logdata=$this->key_logout($ad_data);
```

```html
public function key_logout($ad_data)
{   
    /* keycloak */
    /* Developer: Kowshiga A
       Created at : 26.8.2021 
       Description: Logout session from IDP  (Oauth flow)  
    */

    $key_token=$this->key_get_token();  
    $ad_data['add_token']=$key_token['access_token']; 
    $this->auth_token1 = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$ad_data['add_token']; 
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $this->keycloak_admin_url.'sessions/'.$ad_data['session_id'],
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> FALSE,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'DELETE',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        $this->auth_token1
      ),
    )); 
    $response = curl_exec($curl); 
    curl_close($curl);
    //print_r($response);die;
     return $response;
}
```

Comment: If the session is already expired, then the user is effectively logged out anyway. Furthermore without a session id (since it's expired), how do you expect to access the old session?

Comment: Yes the systems user session is already expired. But I need to expired the session in keycloak as well along with this system's session. For that i Need the user's id. I s there any other way to maintain a user id and use it to logout the keycloak session

Comment: Can you show your code on how you log in users using keycloak?

Comment: The access token lifespan is set to 24 hrs for now which is the requirement from the customer

Comment: So you dont want to share your code?

Comment: This is not in code but it is configured in UI of Keycloak admin console

Comment: So you're saying you have no PHP code that makes use of your keycloak setup?

Comment: Yes i have iwill share it. I have added the logout function in question. Take a look at it.

Comment: _"Is there any other way to maintain a user id"_ - store it into a cookie, separate from the session, and make that cookie *not* expire as quickly as the session does ...? Then on the next request, when you realize the user has no valid session any more, you can trigger your keycloak logout request.

Comment: But then you will still have the problem with sessions that have expired, but that you will get no more requests for. Even if you implement some unload handler that was supposed to fire a request if the user closed their browser, that won't help if, say, my electricity simply cuts out ... If you need to catch those cases as well, then you will have to keep track on what active sessions you have on the server side, and periodically (cron) run a check on those.

Answer (score 0):

By session expiration, User will automatically logout, you dont need to do something !

Comment: Hi I am aware of that already. But there is another session active in Keycloak. Due to that active session in keycloak, again the new session is created.